# How to prepend image in angular datatables customise button print from project folder

Tags: html, angular, angular-datatables

The code angular 8 code below is showing the image with

```
<img src="http://datatables.net/media/images/logo-fade.png" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" />');
```

when i change that line to

```
<img src="assets/dist/img/logo-fade.png" />');
```

the image is not showing on the print preview

```
      [
        {
          extend: 'print',
          title: '',
          customize: function (win) {
            $(win.document.body)
              .css('font-size', '10pt')
              .prepend(
                // '<img src="http://datatables.net/media/images/logo-fade.png" style="position:absolute; 
                     top:0; left:0;" />');
                '<img src="assets/dist/img/logo-fade.png" />');
          }
        },
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
      ]
```